# How to change the default UI from Braintree Card Form with Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the text color and remove this left icon :

[image]

So for the CardNumber I use another view to change individually

```
//ONLY THE CARD ENTRY
<com.braintreepayments.cardform.view.CardForm
        android:id="@+id/card_form"
        style="@style/MyCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
//EXPIRATION,CVV,POSTALCODE
<com.braintreepayments.cardform.view.CardForm
        android:id="@+id/card_formTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And tried to apply this them, but still not working..

```
<style name="MyCard" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:hint">EAEE</item>
</style>
```

[CardForm](https://github.com/braintree/android-card-form)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked if this code works, but I guess it will give you a direction at least. This is how I suppose the icons could be removed:

```
CardForm cardForm = (CardForm) findViewById(R.id.card_form);
cardForm.setCardNumberIcon(0);
cardForm.setPostalCodeIcon(0);
```

The text color on the other hand seems not to be changeable. You can only modify the accent color according to the [documentation on styling](https://github.com/braintree/android-card-form#styling), but you may try to change the textColor too (green for accent and blue for text color in the example below):

```
<style name="MyCard">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#91beae</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#3b5998</item>
</style>
```

Comment: cardForm.setCardNumberIcon(0); remove the right icon of the card brand but not in the left. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

Create a style :

```
<style name="MyCard" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorGrey</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Then don't apply it as a style, but as a theme, So add this to your Card Form:

```
android:theme="@style/MyCard"
```

I hope that works for u too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8bBU.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYgFu.jpg)